# Python Tkinter simple value process

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button

I just new for the GUI and need little help.

```
a=int(input())
if a==0:
   print("hi")
else:
   print("hello")
```

I want to change input process to click button, like a switch.

> left button -> a=0

> right button -> a=1

```
window=tkinter.Tk()
window.title("")
window.geometry("640x640+100+100")
window.resizable(True, True)



a=tkinter.Button(window, text="left")
a.pack()

b=tkinter.Button(window, text="right")
b.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

I can see left, right button but I don't know how to put values.

Is there any example I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Does this example help You:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button


def switch(btn1, btn2):
    btn1.config(state='disabled')
    btn2.config(state='normal')
    print(btn1['text'])


window = Tk()
window.title("")

on = Button(window, text="On", command=lambda: switch(on, off))
on.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='x')

off = Button(window, text="Off", command=lambda: switch(off, on))
off.pack(side='left', expand=True, fill='x')
off.config(state='disabled')

window.mainloop()
```

If You have questions ask but here is pretty [good site](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm) to look up tkinter widgets and what they do, their attributes.

Also I suggest You follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: I usually use [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20201111171246/https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/) website. Also both buttons are already global variables and you can just define 2 function instead of using lambdas

Comment: @TheLizzard but one function keeps it a bit more compact, also that is a great site too I have used it before

Comment: For people starting to learn tkinter it usually isn't a good idea to directly go to `lambda`s. Sometimes they can get very tricky.

Comment: @TheLizzard well they are still a bit tricky to me since I sometimes don't understand why they are missing an argument but in general my simple understanding regarding the use of other functions is that they allow to easily put arguments (I know that they can be used as function definitions on-the-fly but this is how I use them) otherwise for beginners it won't affect them much to write another function instead of using lambdas

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a function to each one that will be executed when the buttons are clicked like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def left_clicked():
    print("Left button clicked")
    right_button.config(state="normal") # Reset the button as normal
    left_button.config(state="disabled") # Disable the button

def right_clicked():
    print("Right button clicked")
    right_button.config(state="disabled")
    left_button.config(state="normal")

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("")
window.geometry("640x640+100+100")
# window.resizable(True, True) # Unneeded as it is already the default

left_button = tk.Button(window, text="left", command=left_clicked)
left_button.pack(side="left")

right_button = tk.Button(window, text="right", command=right_clicked,
                         state="disabled")
right_button.pack(side="right")

window.mainloop()
```